# How to update after "php bin/console security:check"

Tags: php, symfony, akeneo

Symfony write on how to check for security updates: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/security_checker.html and it works, in Akeneo it shows me one vulnerability. 
But how to update? I tried `../composer.phar update` and `../composer.phar update symfony/symfony` but unfortunately the vulnerability is still there when I check again. (https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/issues/7146)

```
/var/www/html/akeneo/pim-community-standard# ../composer.phar why dompdf/dompdf:0.6.1
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
akeneo/pim-community-dev  v2.0.6  requires  dompdf/dompdf (0.6.1)


/var/www/html/akeneo/pim-community-standard# ../composer.phar why-not dompdf/dompdf:0.6.2
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
akeneo/pim-community-dev  v2.0.6  requires  dompdf/dompdf (0.6.1)
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `composer why dompdf/dompdf:0.6.1` and `composer why-not dompdf/dompdf:0.6.2`?

Comment: I have edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security check complains about the package `dompdf/dompdf` being outdated. So you have to find out which dependency is responsible for this package being installed. You can use composer for this:

```
composer why dompdf/dompdf
```

Once you find out why it's installed you can either check if you can update that dependency to a version supporting/requiring a newer dompdf version or if you installed it by requiring it yourself just update it.

Alternatively you can also ask composer why it won't install a new version by using:

```
composer why-not dompdf/dompdf "^0.8"
```

If you can't update whatever dependency depends on the outdated dompdf version you might have to resort to either create a PR in that project for a newer version or forking the project and updating the composer.json yourself (not recommended though, because of the additional work of keeping it up to date).

**edit:** It looks like akeneo itself is responsible for pinning the version as you can see in the repo: https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/2.0/composer.json#L41

Maybe you can create a PR updating the composer.json and maybe loosening the version restriction for dompdf.

Comment: If Akeneo is responsible (the package is old BTW, why didn't they notice earlier), then maybe they should update their code then.

Comment: They did notice earlier. The [issue #5233](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/issues/5233) is linked [in a comment on your issue](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/issues/7146#issuecomment-344186771). It seems they know some dependencies are outdated and if I understand right they plan to address it in the upcoming minor release, so 1.8/2.1 I guess.

Comment: Yes, I think so now.

Answer (score 1):

NicoHaase mentioned the anwser I'd say: https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/issues/7146#issuecomment-344206254

> No one should edit composer.lock. Just read the bug report linked in
>   my former comment: the maintainers of Akeneo know about these outdated
>   packages and plan to fix them anytime in the future

The bug report https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/issues/5233 was created on 17 Nov 2016, but unfortunately still nothing. Devs said to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the answer given at the "bug report" you linked? ;)

Comment: Thanks, for pointing out again. I see now, devs said to wait.